# Can't mount a usb disk in my raspberry pi

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, raspberry-pi

When I execute "sudo blkid" I get:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="boot" UUID="993B-8922" TYPE="vfat"  
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="fc254b57-8fff-4f96-9609-ea202d871acf" TYPE="ext4"  
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Home" UUID="76143D8A143D4E7D" TYPE="ntfs"
```

I want to mount the disk /dev/sdb1, with label Home. But if I execute "sudo fdisk -l":

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 32.1 GB, 32127320064 bytes  
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 980448 cylinders, total 62748672 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0x000981cb  

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/mmcblk0p1    8192        122879      57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)  
   /dev/mmcblk0p2    122880    62748671    31312896   83  Linux
```

I don't see the disk at all. I guess it is a problem with the disk, but is there any way to have it mount?

Update 1: If I execute "tail /var/log/syslog" I get:

```
NTFS-fs error (device sdb1): load_system_files(): Volume is dirty.  Mounting read-only.  Run chkdsk and mount in Windows.
```

Update 2: I connected the disk to a windows machine, I was able to see the disk but when I tried to access it I saw (for half a second) the folders in a window and then the window closed and I was asked to format the disk. Now every time I try to connect the disk to a windows machine, it says that the disk needs to be formatted so there is no way to execute chkdsdk (as far as I know).

What does that mean?

Update 3:

I am getting from Ubuntu:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/GoFlex Home: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/user/GoFlex Home"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=4653056 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Inode is corrupt (0): Input/output error
Failed to open $MFT/$BITMAP: Input/output error
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

but I cant execute chkdsk from windows at any time.

Update 4:

I don't know why, but now I am able to access the disk from Windows. If I start browsing the drive, I get disconnected (couple of clicks somewhere and it is gone the most of the times). I have been able to see the correct disk info with EaseUS, and have been able to execute CHKDSK /F with this output:

```
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
 1 percent complete. (799489 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 799941.
 1 percent complete. (799942 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 799942.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 799943.
 1 percent complete. (926465 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926925.
 1 percent complete. (926926 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926926.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926927.
 1 percent complete. (926928 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926928.
 1 percent complete. (926929 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926929.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926930.
 1 percent complete. (926931 of 5645663 file records processed) 
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926931.
 1 percent complete. (926933 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (160, $I30) from file record segment 926948.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926949.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 926950.
 5 percent complete. (2983937 of 5645663 file records processed)
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 2984377.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 2984378.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "") from file record segment 2984379.
 5 percent complete. (3032833 of 5645663 file records processed)
```

Then it is stopped. So I execute again

```
E:\>chkdsk /f
```

and I get

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
Error in IOCTL call.
```

I've been searching what is that IOCTL call error but it is not clear what is the problem. Does that mean that if I change the controller card I could recover the data?

Thanks!

Comment: It means the volume was flagged as dirty (probably an improper shutdown, common with devices like the Pi), so it's mounting it read only. The suggested solution is to mount the drive in a Windows machine and run `chkdsk`, which will fix this. If you've installed `ntfsprogs` you may also get by running `ntfsck`. By the way, you mount with `mount`, not with `fdisk`, and if you just try and mount the drive with `mount`, usually a reasonable error message will be printed rather than having to hunt through the log.

Comment: Thanks Jason C, yes I tried to mount it with mount :) but didn't work. When I try to connect the disk to windows, it says that the disk needs to be formatted, so I think it could be something else; not sure if it is a drive failure because I was able to see the disk ok.

Comment: Who knows, maybe a bad / odd partition table in addition to filesystem errors or a dirty flag. So repair the MBR if necessary (or use SuperFloppy), format it as FAT32 and be done with it. NTFS support is sometimes iffy on Linux anyways (although mostly decent these days) but [there's really no reason to use it on a USB stick](http://www.howtogeek.com/177529/htg-explains-why-are-removable-drives-still-using-fat32-instead-of-ntfs/) and it will save you some potential headaches.

Comment: Thanks Jason C, but formatting it would make me to lose everything in there :( Is there any way (more than sending it to professional services) to repait the MBR without losing the data? The reason why it is external is because it was a NAS drive (from a Goflex Home, never will use Seagate again...)

Comment: Can `gparted` on Linux or [EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) (free) on Windows see the NTFS partition? If so you could use either of those tools to either copy the *partition* (not the whole drive) to a second drive / USB stick or copy it to an image, reformat the stick, then copy the image back. `gparted` has the ability to search the drive for valid partitions and create a new MBR but it is time consuming and risky. You could try a full Linux distro instead of whatever is on the Pi as well, e.g. an Ubuntu LiveCD or Wubi.

Comment: gparted doesn't work on my Pi (raspian), but EASEUS Partition Master sees it. It says "Basic MBR - Unallocated 1.82 TB". MBR signature is FFFFFFFF, if that helps. And now is when I am starting to be a little bit lost :) - does this mean that the MBR is wrong but the data still could be in there? I will have another bigger NAS available over the weekend so I guess next steps are as you said 1) Backup 2) Reformat 3) Copy back but I am not sure which options would be the ones to be used - I see initialize to GPT(?), Rebuild MBR (?), Surface test, Partition Scheme, Data recovery and Backup tool...

Comment: Jason C, I tried all options with EASEUS but nothing worked. I finally made a back up of the MBR and tried to rebuild it with the EASYUS but I get an error message, "there are some error occurred while reading sector on disk". Any ideas?

Comment: My immediate thought is that the drive is starting to fail. If I were you the next thing I would try is grabbing an Ubuntu Live CD, booting from that and using `gparted` to attempt to "recover partitions"; it will take a while but it will search the whole drive then rebuild the MBR. If the drive is failing, the drivers on Linux might be a little more forgiving than the drivers on Windows. If you get it working this way I suggest backing up all the data on that drive immediately.

Comment: Thanks Jason C. I'm trying to use gparted but it hardly sees my disk, and when it sees it I can do nothing; basically it says unallocated and doesnt give me any other options. However, after several tries, the file system loads the GoFlex Home folder (the main one), and I can access the public folders, but when I try to copy it I get an input/output error and I can't save anything. Still trying, any ideas?

Comment: Well, this is really strange. So ubuntu automatically detects the disk, sometimes it shows the folders, sometimes it doesnt. When the folders are shown, the data is accessible; I can copy it, but after a while the connection is lost, and I cant access it anymore. So I am doing partial backups, from time to time. That is the "Public" part of the disk (this was the disk of a Goflex Home), but I have no way to access my important data so far, the one of my private user. Any ideas?

Comment: It really sounds to me like the drive is trashed. I would keep trying to copy data off of it until you give up, then toss it and buy a new drive. As for techniques for data recovery, it's a whole different question, which you can certainly ask about although please make an effort to look for existing info first. For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=recovering+failed+usb+drive Is it a flash drive or an external hard drive?

Comment: If it's an external hard drive with a USB cable, by the way, just as an easy test try a different USB cable (cross your fingers, but you never know). You could also try removing the drive and putting it in a different enclosure, just to rule that out as well. If it's a thumb drive, or if it's not a cable or enclosure problem, start with the Google search I linked to for some info and techniques.

Comment: It was a NAS drive (Seagate GoFlex Home), now it is a USB drive. I also think that I am in a way to have a brick. About the enclosure, I wasnt able to even read it from the GoFlex, thats why I get a new usb box. I will try the recovering link you posted, but every time it is more complicated to access the disk from ubuntu... sometimes the drive is loaded, I see the Public folder with all the folders, then one disappears, then the drive is disconnected....

Comment: If you can pull the drive out of its enclosure and connect to it directly you could check the SMART data with [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) and see if there are any warning signs. You could also try SpinRite, it is expensive (~$80), time consuming, and sometimes of limited use, but when it works it works really well and if you aren't satisfied they *do* honor their money-back guarantees.

Comment: Tried to use CrystalDiskInfo but I still can not mount the drive in Windows, so didn work. From Ubuntu, I still have the same problem, the disk tries to mount it, sometimes it does but then it gets unmounted after a couple of mins (or less), sometimes is just not mounted. Is SpinRite going to be a possibility in this situation? By the moment I am not going to be able to put the disk in a desktop computer.

Comment: SpinRite might help. It might not. And even if it helps some of the drive there's no guarantee it will be mountable in Windows again. At this point it's really a bit of an art, unfortunately. There's some good recovery tools out there that can help you if you search around a bit.

Comment: Well, several days without going back to the disk, I started it in ubuntu, same problem, tested by the last time in windows and now I "can" access it. I've been able to execute chkdsk /f but after some time it either is deactivated (?!) or I get this message: "Error in IOCTL call". I've been searching for that but I am not sure what does that mean